# why is python generating a half space when printing from a string or list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
finale_line=[]
print type(finale_line)#just checking#
lot_number=()
number_drawn=()
def load():  
    first=input("enter first lot: ")
    last=input("enter last lot: ")
    for lot_number in range(first,last):
        line_out=str(lot_number)            
        for count in range(1,5):
            number_drawn=raw_input("number: ")  
            line_out=line_out+number_drawn
        print line_out        #making sure it's a string at this point#
        finale_line.append(line_out)                
finale_line2=finale_line                        

load()


print finale_line  #again just checking#
print(" "*4),
for n in range(1,21):
    print n,          #this is to produce a line of numbers to compare to output#  
for a in finale_line:    
    print"\n",    
    print a[0]," ",    
    space_count=1
    for b in range(1,5):
        if int(a[b])<10:
            print(" "*(int(a[b])-space_count)),int(a[b]),
            space_count=int(a[b])
        else:                   
            print(" "*(a[b]-space_count)),a[b],
            space_count=a[b]+1
```

I apologize for not actually phrasing a "?" This would have cost me on Jeopardy. 2: I posted twice because I thought the first one was messed up.And 3: The code posted was an old defunct version but what worries me is you got a different error message than I did. I'm not sure this version will yield the same results on your machine. This has been an on-going problem with python.

```
>>>
<type 'list'>
enter first lot: 1
enter last lot: 4
number: 2
number: 3
number: 4
number: 5
12345
number: 1
number: 2
number: 3
number: 4
21234
number: 3
number: 4
number: 5
number: 6
33456
['12345', '21234', '33456']
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
1     2   3   4   5 
2    1   2   3   4 
3      3   4   5   6
>>>
```

I realize there is problem with my logic in the spacing but I think this can be fixed.What I don't understand is where the half space is coming from. Or maybe a completely different approach is required. Thank you for responding and I don't wish to waste anyone's time but it greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but where in your output is there a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your intended output would be, but I suspect that using `str.join` and/or `format` will be much easier than manually spacing things. Try: `print "".join(format(num, "<4") for num in list_of_numbers` and adjust the width as desired. I'm not sure why you're packing your sequences of numbers into a single string, as this will break with numbers that have two or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by a "half" space, but I think what's confusing you is the "extra" space that you think shouldn't be showing up in between your numbers; am I right?

If that's the case, then that's coming from the final comma in your `print` statements. You're using it to stop `print` from printing a newline after its output -- but what you don't realize is that it's printing an extra space when it hits that comma. Try this at the Python command prompt:

```
>>> def hello():
...     print "Hello",
...     print "world"
... 
>>> hello()
Hello world
```

I didn't put a space after "Hello", so where did it come from? Answer: the comma.

Your confusion is mostly stemming from two things: 1) using the wrong tool for the job, and 2) a lack of in-depth understanding of how Python does output (understandable in a Python beginner).

Problem 1 can be solved by using `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print`. (Do note that you'll need to `import sys` before you can use it). `write()` does not add any spaces or newlines; you'll need to specify the spaces and the newlines yourself. (Newlines are `\n` in Python strings, in case you've forgotten). So your output will be more predictable.

Problem 2 can be solved by working your way through http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html as soon as possible. Notice the use of string methods like `.rjust()` and `.format()`: get used to those methods and you'll learn to love them. In fact, you'll soon wonder why in the world you would *ever* want to do this sort of string formatting by hand anymore, when such powerful functions are available to do it for you.

Hope this helps, and enjoy learning Python!